# get array length in mongoose without aggregate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**I have this model:**

```
const postSchema = Schema(
  {
    author: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
    },
    likes: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Like",
      },],         
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

i want to get the likes count (the length of the likes array) without using aggregate : is this possible ?

```
exports.getAllPosts = async (req, res) => {
  const allPosts = await Post.find()
  .populate({ path: "author", select: "firstName lastName email" })
    .populate({ path: "likes" })
    .then((posts) => {
      return res.status(200).json({ Posts_count: postsCount , posts});
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return res.status(404).json(err);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, But you can maintain your own count and update it whenever item in Like is added or removed. You can use schema.pre middleware, For more please see https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html